# Drop stderr from ls

Tags: shell, ls, tcsh

When I run `ls` on a filename that doesn't exist the output reports that. I'd like to drop that output but still report when a file is found. Is this stderr that reports the output below?

```
$> ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
```

I'm using tcsh, but bash could work as an alternative.

Comment: Something like this (in bash): `ls foo 2>/dev/null`

Comment: In Bash (or any other standards-compliant shell) one can redirect standard output separately, e.g., `2> /dev/null ls foo`. No idea if it can be done in Tcsh. But `test -e foo && ls foo` should always work.

Comment: @AlexP: `standards-compliant shell` - https://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 2):

> Is this stderr that reports the output below?

Yes, most probably - it depends on the version of `ls` you're using
but I believe most implementations print errors to stderr.  To get rid
of stderr in `tcsh`:

```
( ls foo > /dev/tty ) >& /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always:

```
sh -c 'ls foo 2>/dev/null'
```

Is that cheating?